# Is it possible to write a verifier that checks if a given program implements a given algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, automation

Given a program P, written in C++, can I write an algorithm that find if the program P implements a particular algorithm? Is there any algorithm that solves this problem. Is this problem solvable?

For example I ask a person to implement quick sort algorithm and now if I want to make sure that the person actually implemented quick sort algorithm. The person can actually implement some other sorting algorithm and it will produce correct output and pass all testcases (black box testing). One way I can do this is look into source code. I want to avoid this manual effort and want to write a program that can do this job. The question is "Is that possible?".

Comment: How about having the person use an abstract interface for some of the low level operations, such as accessing the elements and swapping.  Then pass them a concrete object that makes sure the caller calls those operations in the way that quicksort would.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Rice's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), you cannot even in general decide whether a piece of code is a sort function or not by examining the code. You can, of course, find out whether it has the effect of sorting for some finite set of inputs by running it with those inputs and examining the results.

You may be able to do something for the specific case of a given target sort algorithm, by examining the array that is being sorted during the sort, checking for invariants that are characteristic of the target algorithm. For example, each call in a recursive quick sort implementation will result in a subarray becoming sorted.

=================================================================

Following on from the comments, I suggest looking at [Ahmad Taherkhani's home page](http://www.cs.hut.fi/~ahmad/). He has continued research in this area, including a 2012 paper on the topic.

Comment: thanks that really helped. I am wondering will it work if we use some set of sample programs implementing the algorithm and then we try to classify a program. Like they do in machine learning problems.

Comment: @Aryaveer The key to doing that would be to find features you can extract from the text such that points that are close together in the feature space represent similar algorithms. I did some web searching, and found [Static Program Analysis for Recognizing Sorting Algorithms](www.cs.hut.fi/~ahmad/mastersthesis.pdf). It's a 2008 paper but may be a useful starting point for citation searching to find the state of the art.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking, and still thinking of stack/heap checks (given you testing against optimized solutions as well).
You can check the time complexity and overall memory complexity which will narrow the results. even for Time: O(n lg n) for merge and quick sorts. you can distinguished them with the memory allocation since they are N ,Lg(n) in order.
you can also check for things like original array disturbance..etc but this is not of decisive weight.